# Как перенести данные с одного телефона на другой?

Tags: android

Здравствуете!Как перенести данные с одного андроид телефона на другой андроид телефон без рута? Нужно перенести контакты, смс, фото. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для windows есть такая программа - MyPhoneExplorer. На устройство с android ставится клиент. В итоге можно как делать бакапы на компьютер, таки и восстанавливать данные на устройство...

Answer (score 1):

Завести аккаунт Google, войти в него на обоих аппаратах и включить синхронизацию.

А фото через блютус, комп, sd-card.

Comment: Я собственно так и сделал, но как контакты из аккаунт Google обратно в телефон переписать?Синхронизация не прокатила на 2 разных телефонах.Отображаются контакты в гугл аккаунте и на телефоне, а нужно всё переписать в сам телефон. Как?

Comment: Собственно зачем?? Они и так в телефоне останутся.. ну да ладно,В телефонной книге нажимаешь "Создать копию контактов" -> "На карту памяти", потом "Импорт контактов" -> "С карты памяти" -> "В телефон"